# Alternativa al control File Upload de asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, fileupload

estoy buscando una alternativa al control File Upload. Estoy trabajando en Vb.Net, asp.net, y webforms ,en visual studio 2013.
El control de asp.net tiene una sola forma visual, no permite drag and drop, y tampoco previsualización. Conocen algun control que cumpla esas expectativas?

Me parece feo, y un poco impráctico.

Gracias

Comment: Algo similar a esto? Dale una mirada a los ejemplos >[www.plupload.com](https://www.plupload.com) puedes subir archivos múltiples. O este otro con [puro HTML5](https://html5demos.com/dnd-upload/). Comentanos específicamente que estás buscando y te ayudaremos a mapearlo para webforms

Comment: ok, gracias... dame un tiempo para que lo investigue y vemos si es lo que necesito. Simplemente quiero subir archivos, pero el control que trae asp.net me parece feo, y poco estético, ademas que no tiene funciones como drag and drop, vista previa y esas cosas.

Comment: con eso que escribiste podés reformular la.pregunta para que no se de opinión. O sea...algo más.especifico con uno de esos ejemplos adaptados para ser utilizados en webforms. Recomendacion: Dale una mirada, prueba en webforms y pregunta algo específico de esa prueba o algo que de bloqueé al adaptarlos.

Comment: lo que pasa es que simplemente quiero investigar opciones... no hay un requerimiento específico... con lo que me dieron está bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto lo impractico, en lo personal siendo una herramienta nativa del IDE diria que el fileupload es lo mas practico, en cuanto al diseño puedes usar CSS para cambiar los diseños, de cualquier forma te dejo una recomendacion de alternativa y una de CSS.

[Alternativa fineuploader](https://fineuploader.com/demos.html)

[Ejemplo con Jquery y CSS](https://www.jquery-az.com/bootstrap-jquery-input-type-file-upload-buttons-and-script/)

En el ultimo puedes tomar la forma con jquery o puedes usarlo directamente con el fileupload de .net agregandole los estilos que usan en el link.

Saludos.